# log4j2 Logger Only Works in Primary Class - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to use log4j2's rolling logs functionality for a new app, but I can't get the logger to work outside the main class, trying various combos of static, final, and autowired configs in the secondary classes.

All classes and config below. What am I missing or incorrectly calling?

**POM.XML**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Root Class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DocumentServiceApplication {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DocumentServiceApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            //these work.
        logger.debug("Logger correctly configured debug.");
        logger.error("Logger correctly configured error.");
        logger.info("Logger correctly configured info.");

        SpringApplication.run(DocumentServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Secondary (Web API) Class:**

```
@RestController
public class DocumentController {

    @Autowired
    private PPAFileService ppaFileService;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DocumentController.class);

    @GetMapping("/ppa/process")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> process( ) throws Exception
    {
        try {
            //this logging gives no error and no entry on console or file.
            logger.debug("Received request for PPA file.");
            ...

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

**Log Output**

```
2019-04-10 15:37:56 DEBUG Logger correctly configured debug.
2019-04-10 15:37:56 ERROR Logger correctly configured error.
2019-04-10 15:37:56 INFO  Logger correctly configured info.
```

**log4j2.properties**

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

#Make sure to change log file path as per your need

property.filename = D:\\projects\\app\\application.log

filters = threshold
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = rolling

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = application-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = com.app.documentservice
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Comment: Just FYI, using static loggers like this is considered gauche/poor practice.  Instead you should `get()` the logger only when you need it, and release the reference as soon as you finish with it.  Unfortunately, I don't know what might be causing the problem with Spring Boot.

Comment: Well since the logger is thread-safe, that seems like a fairly trite standard of poor practice, not to mention pointless code bloat to get a handle in every function. Still, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: It's not thread safety, it's the start up cost which is added to each and every class, plus those references can never be garbage collected.  Seriously, this style was in vogue like 15 years ago, but I haven't seen it advocated since then.

Comment: Just benchmarked vs. the factory-ised version, and less than 30ms difference 99th percentile after 200 runs. Look, as a Master of CS, I get that performance matters at grand scale, but at that point I wouldn't even be using Spring Boot. This is immaterial to the problem. And it didn't SOLVE the problem.